# Poker hand probabilities

Tags: probability, poker

I am very bad at probability problems in math. There is a homework question such that:

> During a game of poker, you are dealt a five-card hand at random.
>   With the convention that aces may count high or low, show that;
>
> P(one pair) = 0.46

I dont know this is easy or not, but I am working on this question for a day. Can you give me some intution or show me how to solve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does it mean "aces may count high or low", since in a pair relative value does not count?

Comment: How sure are you of the 0.46 answer?  When I do the calculation, I get 0.422569. I don't see what the aces/high low thing has to do with it, however, so maybe I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is all solutions (one pair, flush etc.) :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the probability of having a pair: $P(\textrm{pair}) = 1 - P(\textrm{no pair}) = 1 - \frac{48}{51} \frac{44}{50} \frac{40}{49} \frac{36}{48} = \frac{2053}{4165} \approx 0.4929$.

To calculate the probability of having exactly one pair (and no better hand): There are $13$ possibilities for the rank of the pair, and $6$ possibilities for the suits of the cards in the pair. Furthermore, there are $12 \choose 3$ possibilities for the ranks of the other cards, which can be of any suit. So the probability is: $$P(\textrm{exactly one pair}) = \frac{13 \cdot 6 \cdot {12 \choose 3} \cdot 4^3}{52 \choose 5} = \frac{352}{833} \approx 0.4226$$.

Comment: How can you be sure that it will be lower than 0.46? There is question similar to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222974/probability-of-getting-2-aces-2-kings-and-1-queen-in-a-five-card-poker-hand-pa I dont think that it will take too long calculations

Comment: It was just intuition saying that it had to be lower than $0.46$. You're right, it's not too much work, as I didn't realize that you cannot get a straight, flush or any other better hand if you have exactly one pair. I have added the full solution now.